# Steady meeting room for Zoom office hours, ready at any time

Tags: teaching, video-conference, remote-work

I would like to have my office hours via Zoom with

1. A link that doesn't change, so it's easy to find the meeting, and
2. I can join my meeting at any time, if the need shows up, not just a scheduled times.

I already know how to address the first problem, namely with repeated scheduled meetings. But I don't know how to address (2) as well. What is the best practice?

Comment: Personal meeting room. Set your number it will never change. You can use anytime without scheduling.

Comment: My issue with the personal meeting room is that I want a seperate course meeting room. For example, I don't want undergraduate students to zoom bomb my research meetings with nude pictures.

Comment: So maybe personal meeting room with a Waiting room?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This semester, I was able to join my office hours for a scheduled meeting at any time, even outside the window of the scheduled meeting.

Zoom has a checkbox “Allow participants to join anytime” that may be selected when creating the scheduled meetings. You will get an email notification if someone joins when you are not there. This allows students to join at any time.

Because the meeting ID does not change, this satisfies your link request.

Disclaimer: I do not know if I have a special version of Zoom; whatever the university provides is what I have.